# Is it possible to run a qemu image build with yocto in docker container?

Tags: docker, yocto, qemu

I built a qemuarm64 image with yocto and I would like to be able to run it in a docker container.

Is that possible ?

Here are the files generated for the image:

```
Image
Image--5.4.178+gitAUTOINC+e8c675c7e1_bf6581eba1-r0-qemuarm64-20220414191357.bin
Image-qemuarm64.bin
modules--5.4.178+gitAUTOINC+e8c675c7e1_bf6581eba1-r0-qemuarm64-20220414191357.tgz
modules-qemuarm64.tgz
radio-image-qemuarm64-20220415164314.qemuboot.conf
radio-image-qemuarm64-20220415164314.rootfs.ext4
radio-image-qemuarm64-20220415164314.rootfs.manifest
radio-image-qemuarm64-20220415164314.rootfs.tar.bz2
radio-image-qemuarm64-20220415164314.testdata.json
radio-image-qemuarm64.ext4
radio-image-qemuarm64.manifest
radio-image-qemuarm64.qemuboot.conf
radio-image-qemuarm64.tar.bz2
radio-image-qemuarm64.testdata.json
```

And here is the configuration file for the runqemu command (radio-image-qemuarm64.qemuboot.conf):

```
[config_bsp]
deploy_dir_image = .
image_link_name = radio-image-qemuarm64
image_name = radio-image-qemuarm64-20220415164314
kernel_imagetype = Image
machine = qemuarm64
qb_cmdline_ip_slirp = ip=dhcp
qb_cmdline_ip_tap = ip=192.168.7.@CLIENT@::192.168.7.@GATEWAY@:255.255.255.0
qb_cpu = -cpu cortex-a57
qb_cpu_kvm = -cpu host -machine gic-version=3
qb_default_fstype = ext4
qb_default_kernel = Image--5.4.178+gitAUTOINC+e8c675c7e1_bf6581eba1-r0-qemuarm64-20220414191357.bin
qb_drive_type = /dev/sd
qb_kernel_cmdline_append = console=ttyAMA0
qb_machine = -machine virt
qb_mem = -m 256
qb_network_device = -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=@MAC@
qb_opt_append = -show-cursor -device VGA,edid=on -device qemu-xhci -device usb-tablet -device usb-kbd -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0
qb_rootfs_extra_opt = 
qb_rootfs_opt = -drive id=disk0,file=@ROOTFS@,if=none,format=raw -device virtio-blk-device,drive=disk0
qb_serial_opt = -device virtio-serial-device -chardev null,id=virtcon -device virtconsole,chardev=virtcon
qb_system_name = qemu-system-aarch64
qb_tap_opt = -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=@TAP@,script=no,downscript=no
qb_tcpserial_opt = -device virtio-serial-device -chardev socket,id=virtcon,port=@PORT@,host=127.0.0.1 -device virtconsole,chardev=virtcon
staging_bindir_native = ../../../work/x86_64-linux/qemu-helper-native/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin
staging_dir_host = ../../../work/qemuarm64-poky-linux/radio-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot
staging_dir_native = ../../../work/qemuarm64-poky-linux/radio-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native
tune_arch = aarch64
```

Comment: Have you find a solution? I am also interested on this topic

Comment: Unfortunately no, I couldn't find anything.